# Cross compiling Qt on windows for raspberry pi, missing xcb dependencies

Tags: linux, windows, cross-compilation, qt

I am trying to start with Qt for Raspberry Pi on a Windows Dev System. To begin with to setup the environment, I followed the below as per the official wiki [page](https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/).

From starting at various stages, I have found this page to be outdated though its the best among the many I have come across. Raspberry Pi OS distribution and supporting distribution are much more updated than those mentioned in the wiki and that causes a lots of background work to be done.

Now, I was configuring the script to build the entire Qt framework. Unfortunately, configuration fails every time.

For configuring I used:

```
../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/configure -platform win32-g++ -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi2-g++ -sysroot C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot -prefix /usr/local/qt5 -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -qt-xcb
```

with `VERBOSE` I understand problem can be due to missing dependencies of `xcb`, mentioned in `src/plugins/platforms/xcb/README`.

which are:

```
libxcb1 libxcb1-dev libx11-xcb1 libx11-xcb-dev libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-keysyms1-dev libxcb-image0 libxcb-image0-dev libxcb-shm0 libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-icccm1 libxcb-icccm1-dev libxcb-sync0 libxcb-sync0-dev libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-render-util0-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxrender-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-glx0-dev
```

But how do I configure these dependencies and make it work? I couldn't find anything suitable for these, that will run on a Windows System. Or is there any out-of-the-box solution, that could make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The important stuff happens in step 6 of the sysprogs tutorial:
There the libraries and headers of your Raspberry Pi get synced over to your Windows PC. However, it looks like some required -dev packages are not installed on your Raspberry Pi.

The following steps might solve the issue:

- Install the required packages using `sudo apt install libxcb1 libxcb1-dev` on your Raspberry Pi.
- Repeat step 6 of the sysprogs tutorial. It will sync the additional headers and libraries to your Windows PC.
- If you find out that additional libraries are missing, repeat the above steps for those libraries.